# How does random numbers generated using pagemap

Tags: java, wicket

Can anyone kindly explain how does page map works and how its generating the page numbers and versions dynamically in wicket and what is the need to keep track of history of pages and what is the threshold of it?The things about page map regarding how it works which they given in most of forums changes when i try to replicate with the real time example.So,kindly help me.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code?

Comment: The source code for Wicket.  Duh!

Comment: Generating page numbers..does it relate anything with source code?

Comment: The Wicket source code includes (I assume) the source code for the methods that generate the page numbers.  If you find and read that part of the source code, you should be able understand how the page map works, and how it is generating the page numbers and versions ... and probably the rest of your question.  If you don't understand parts of the source code, ask a MORE SPECIFIC followup question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look:
[Apache Wicket - Page maps](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/page-maps.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But when i try to replicate in my application it is not reflected correctly as they have mentioned in that page.